# Function form check using JavaScript not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am testing out a pop out form whenever a button is clicked. I have it in a div tag and hidden using display: none. I am trying to make it appear when I click on my button however nothing shows up.

HTML:

Form:

```
<div class="form_main_bg">
</div>
<div class="form_box">
  <div class="form_header">Pop out</div>
  <div class="form_body"></div>
  <div class="form_footer">
    <button class="btn form-control color-white mwc-orange-background-color" onclick="closeform()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Button:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn form-control color-white mwc-orange-background-color" id="register" name="register" value="REGISTER" onclick="formcheck()">
```

Javascript:

```
function  closeform() {
  var main_bg = document.getElementByClass("form_main_bg");
  var f_box = document.getElementByClass("form_box");
  main_bg.style.display = "none";
  f_box.style.display = "none";
}

function formcheck() {

    var main_bg = document.getElementByClass("form_main_bg");
    var f_box = document.getElementByClass("form_box");
    main_bg.style.display = "block";
    f_box.style.display = "block";

    var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var winHeight = window.innerHeight;

    f_box.style.left = (winWidth/2) - 400/2 + "px";
    f_box.style.top = "150px";
}
```

UPDATE: I tried "getElementByClass", still no effect.

I also tried: querySelector('.form_main_bg'); and getElementsByClassName("form_main_bg"); still nothing

Comment: There's no `<input name="fname">` in the form.

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: You are trying to get element by id, but in HTML you are setting classes.

Comment: i updated my answer regarding the two issues brought up here

Comment: i also tried: querySelector('.form_main_bg'); and getElementsByClassName("form_main_bg"); still nothing

Comment: You need to update your code from this main_bg.style.display = "block"; to main_bg[0].style.display = "block";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

First the function is not `document.getElementByClass` but `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Second, the result of `document.getElementsByClassName` will be an array with all elements that has the specified class. So you have to select an item from the result before applying styles. (`main_bg[0].style.display`)

See the code below.

```js
function closeform() {
  var main_bg = document.getElementsByClassName("form_main_bg");
  var f_box = document.getElementsByClassName("form_box");
  main_bg[0].style.display = "none";
  f_box[0].style.display = "none";
}

function formcheck() {

  var main_bg = document.getElementsByClassName("form_main_bg");
  var f_box = document.getElementsByClassName("form_box");
  main_bg[0].style.display = "block";
  f_box[0].style.display = "block";

  var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var winHeight = window.innerHeight;

  f_box[0].style.left = (winWidth / 2) - 400 / 2 + "px";
  f_box[0].style.top = "150px";
}
```

```html
<div class="form_main_bg">
</div>
<div class="form_box">
  <div class="form_header">Pop out</div>
  <div class="form_body"></div>
  <div class="form_footer">
    <button class="btn form-control color-white mwc-orange-background-color" onclick="closeform()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="btn form-control color-white mwc-orange-background-color" id="register" name="register" value="REGISTER" onclick="formcheck()">
```

Comment: this kind of works, but the pop up only stays for a quick second then disappears again

Comment: Are you sure? When I run the code snippet here, it seems to work properly.

Comment: my bad, i just had to "return false;" some other code was affecting the form.